# How to get xbox one to read from dlna

Tags: xbox-one

I put my usb stick into my asus router and enabled the content to source as dnla

How do I get the xbox one to play movies shared as part of the dnla share?

Comment: Pretty sure the Xbox One is not capable of doing this. You need a DLNA share that you can force to start sending content to the XBO, without the XBO requesting it. [Some details](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/125228-xbox-one-how-to-stream-content-using-dlna)

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure full DLNA support is in the pipeline but not currently in the latest firmware for Xbox One

Comment: I don't get how this system can be so pathetically outdated (less ability than ps3) and lacking technology.

Comment: The same way the ps4 can be, it's not considered a priority by the developers. If this is such a major deal for you, you should have done some research before making a purchase.

Comment: Sure it's easy to point fingers, but no sane person would fault someone got thinking the new wave of latest and greatest systems would at the least perform more and better than previous generation systems. What happened to being the center of your home entertainment? More like an isolated corner ...

Answer (score 0):

The Xbox One can only act as a DLNA reciever. You can use the 'Play to...' feature from a DLNA server/compatible device to send the video to your Xbox One, but it can not actively search or browse for content to play.

For a more expanded answer, see here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/144909/49600